# Dealing with SAS Sessions while running a Stored Process

Tags: vba, sas

Currently I am trying to run a *SAS* program using *VBA*. Using the *SAS Add-In For Microsoft Office*, I created a stored process that contains a generic code that creates a dummy table. Inside *SAS EG*, I am able to run the *Stored Process* normally, and also inside the *Excel* environment, using the *InsertStoredProcess* function of the *SASExcelAddIn* object. Regardless of the environment used to run my *Stored Process*, the behavior of the *SAS Sessions* are the same: one session is created when I start to run and another one is created during the process. However, that is where my problem comes. When the process finishes, I continue with the two sessions as active, and every time I try to run again my *Stored Process*, one new session is created over the ones that already existed. The sessions close only when I manually disconnect from the *SAS Server* I'm connected or when I close the *Excel*. Since my organization allows only three concurrent sessions, this is becoming a big problem for me.

I already tried to use the *ABORT* macro function inside my code, the *rc=stpsrv_session('delete')* command and delete the *Stored Process* from the *Excel* worksheet, and none of them solved my problem.

Any ideas of what I'm missing here? Is there a way to end the *SAS Session* after the *Stored Process* ends?

Comment: Really sounds like a question you should ask SAS Support.  You are paying them to help you so take advantage of it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't use VBA to do any of this. If in Office products, use VSTO and C#. I am in the throes of converting thousands of lines of VBA to C#/VSTO. VBA is very obsolete which is why the code is being converted.

Second, EG is built using C# so it is more natural to use. You can even create custom tasks using C# in EG.

You need to close out your sessions after they are started. See this post at SAS for how to close out your sessions in VBA: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Enterprise-Guide/Calling-SAS-through-VBA/td-p/79673

Again, you should stop using VBA and switch over. It will be much easier. VSTO is free and is made to interact with Office. Use Visual Studio to create your project. The C# code for working with SAS can be found using any of Chris Hemendinger's post (SAS community manager) or you can refer to links on my github repos here: https://github.com/savian-net